# Raphael.js newbie question: how to create a rectangular and lines as ONE object?

Tags: javascript, raphael

In **raphael**, if I want to render the following shape:
[image]

I have to do something like:

```
var paper = Raphael("notepad", 320, 200);

var rect = paper.rect(...);
var line1 = paper.path(...);
var line2 = paper.path(...);
```

which create **three** elements: `rect`, `line1`, `line2`.

BUT, I would like to treat the rendered shape as **one object** in other js code insteand of three. In Raphael, how can I create this shape which returns me just **one object** not three?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to create a [`set`](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#set).

> Creates array-like object to keep and operate couple of elements at once. Warning: it doesn't create any elements for itself in the page.
>
> ```
> var st = paper.set();
> st.push(
>     paper.circle(10, 10, 5),
>     paper.circle(30, 10, 5)
> );
> st.attr({fill: "red"});
> ```

Your code would look something like this:

```
var paper = Raphael("notepad", 320, 200),
    st = paper.set();

st.push(
    paper.rect(...),
    paper.path(...),
    paper.path(...)
);

// use st elsewhere
```

---

***Edit***

> How can I access individual element in the set then?

You can grab references to the objects before you add them to the set:

```
var paper = Raphael("notepad", 320, 200),
    st = paper.set(),
    rect1 = paper.rect(...),
    path1 = paper.path(...),
    path2 = paper.path(...);

st.push(rect1, path1, path2);
```

I'm not 100% sure, but since the docs say that a set is "array-like," then you should also be able to access elements in the set using array index notation:

```
var i, elt;
for (i=0; i<st.length; i++)
{
    elt = st[i];
    // do stuff with elt
}
```

Comment: how can I access individual element in the set then?